# Apache camel file encrypt/ ftp upload woes on Windows

Tags: java, windows, encryption, ftp, apache-camel

I have a java web application that creates a file in a folder. These files are picked up by a camel route that pgp encrypts it and then ftp's it. Initially, I had it as one route and it worked on my windows servers. Then it stopped working. So, I split it into two routes that way even if ftp fails I won't have unencrypted files lying on the server. Plus, I can manually ftp those, if needed (not ideal). Now, it works on one server but not another. Both are windows servers, my application server is tomcat.

Is there a reliable way to make this work across servers?

The routes are shown below

```
<route id="file_encrypt">
  <from uri="file://{{rootOutputDirectory}}/thirdparty/outbound?readLock=rename&amp;delete=true"/>
  <setHeader headerName="cryptoKeyFile">
    <simple>${properties:thirdparty.pgpkey}</simple>
  </setHeader>
  <to uri="bean:PGPEncryptProcessor"/>
  <to uri="file://{{rootOutputDirectory}}/thirdparty/outbound/encrypted"/>
</route>

<route id="file_ftp">
  <from uri="file://{{rootOutputDirectory}}/thirdparty/outbound/encrypted/?readLock=rename&amp;move=.done&amp;moveFailed=.error"/>
  <to uri="ftp://{{thirdparty.ftp.user}}@{{thirdparty.ftp.url}}{{thirdparty.ftp.outgoingdir}}/?password={{thirdparty.ftp.password}}&amp;binary=true"/>
</route>
```

The value of `thirdparty.ftp.outgoingdir` is

```
thirdparty.ftp.outgoingdir=/test/incoming
```

I see the following error in the log

```
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: File operation failed: 550 Failed to change directory.
```

It seems like the issue listed here - http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Cannot-change-directory-to-quot-Code-550-on-FTP-component-td5734612.html. However, it is not clear why it works on one server but not another with the same settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the commons-net version was different across different servers - one had 3.1 (works) and other had 3.2 (doesn't work). I am not sure how that happened (looking into it). However, switching the commons-net to 3.1 across all servers got it working.